# I have managed to create an infinite while loop in python 3

Tags: python

I have managed to create an infinite while loop (it keeps on showing the high scores bit repeatedly) on python, and am having trouble correcting it, any ideas?

I added a break in after the high scores bit and that stopped the infinite loop but the program would then ask the person to press the exit button once they had imputed their choice even if they hadn't pressed 0.

```
#high scores
#demonstrates list methods

scores = []

choice = None

while choice != "0":
    print(
    """
High Scores

0 - Exit
1 - Show Scores
2 - Add a Score
3 - Delete a Score
4 - Sort Scores
"""
)

choice = input("Choice: ")
print()

#exit
if choice == "0":
    print("Goodbye")

#list high scores table
elif choice == "1":
    print("High Scores")
    for score in scores:
        print(score)

#add a score
elif choice == "2":
    score = int(input("What score did you get?: "))
    scores.append(score)

#remove a score
elif choice == "3":
    score = int(input("Remove which score?: "))
    if score in scores:
        scores.remove(score)
    else:
        print(score, "isn't in the high score list.")

#sort scores
elif choice == "4":
    scores.sort(reverse=True)

#some unknown choice
else:
    print("Sorry, but", choice, "isn't a valid choice.")


input("\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Correct your indention!

Comment: Step through your code using [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). It will diagnose everything similar to this.

Comment: this is for python 3, sorry I didn't make that very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have the `print` indented, so the remaining lines are not part of the while block

Answer (score 0):

If this is Python 2.x, use `raw_input`, `input` gives you an integer which does not equal the string `"0"`, also `input` is evil because it is a security problem.

Also indentation.

Answer (score 0):

The input() function automatically converts its result to an integer (because it's calling eval), so you might want to compare with 0 instead of "0":

```
if choice == 0:
  print("bye")
```

But the more sensible choice is to use raw_input:

```
choice = raw_input("Choice: ")

if choice == "0":
  print("bye")
```

See [Python 2.7 docs on input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: The title says Python3, which is good because we'd want to discourage using `eval` or `input` in Python2

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked this.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may want to try this:

```
choice = input(int("Choice: "))
```

This will make choice a type integer and help prevent a mix-up of different types which the compiler will throw an error if it is looking for one type but it gets another.

For example, with the code I gave I can give a choice of 2 and it would be of the integer type. Or with yours, I could give a 2 and it might be of the string type.

I'm a little rusty on this so what I say may not even matter. Just throwing it out there.